# How to change color of ButtonGroup in Material UI with React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to to something like this using Material UI (https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0aUV.png)

I've used ButtonGroup but I dont know how to change the color of the borders.

At this moment I have this:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg3xZ.png)

My code:

```js
<Grid item lg={4} className={style.navGridCenter}>
  <ButtonGroup variant='text' aria-label='text button group' sx={{ background: '#566673','& .MuiButtonGroup-groupedText':{borderColor:'#fff'}}}>

    <Tooltip title="Empresa">
      <Button className={style.navCenterBtn} disableRipple id="Empresa" variant='text'>
        Empresa
      </Button>
    </Tooltip>

    <Tooltip title="Local">
      <Button className={style.navCenterBtn} disableRipple id="Localização" variant='text' aria-label='Localização'>
        Localização
      </Button>
    </Tooltip>

    <Tooltip title="Função">
      <Button className={style.navCenterBtn} disableRipple id="Função do Utilizador" variant='text' aria-label='Função do Utilizador'>
        Função do Utilizador
      </Button>
    </Tooltip>
  </ButtonGroup>
</Grid>
```

I need to change the border color of the ButtonGroup to #ffffff.
I've tried this but it didn't work

```js
sx={{'& .MuiButtonGroup-groupedText':{borderColor:'#fff'}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.MuiButtonGroup-grouped:not(:last-of-type)` class to style the borders. If you just want to change the color use `borderColor` to not override the other border styles.

```js
<ButtonGroup
  sx={{
    ".MuiButtonGroup-grouped:not(:last-of-type)": {
      borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
    },
  }}
  variant="text"
  aria-label="text button group"
>
```

Comment: it worked, but how can i change the height of the border?

Comment: They depend on the size of the `Button` you could add some vertical padding with e.g. `py: 2`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the pseudo class selector you have (i.e. `& .MuiButtonGroup-groupedText`), just simply use the `border` property inside `sx`. The problem is that you are not setting the width of the border, only the color. Your changes are not showing because the width is 0 I believe. You are need to tell it what type of border. In your case, I am assuming you want a `solid` border.

```
<ButtonGroup
  variant="text"
  aria-label="text button group"
  sx={{
    background: "#566673",
    border: "1px solid white"
  }}
>
...
</ButtonGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to customize `ButtonGroup` based on your Screenshot.

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-payne-ctwkmi?file=/src/App.js:0-1427

```
import "./styles.css";
import { ButtonGroup, Button, Divider } from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ButtonGroup
        sx={{
          ".MuiButtonGroup-grouped": {
            borderColor: "transparent",
            borderRadius: 6,
            borderWidth: 3,
            "&:hover": {
              borderColor: "transparent"
            }
          },
          ".MuiButtonGroup-grouped:not(:last-of-type)": {
            "&:hover": {
              borderRightColor: "transparent"
            }
          },
          background: "#4C6C7B",
          borderRadius: 6
        }}
      >
        <Button sx={{ background: "#4c6c7b", color: "#FFF", py: 2 }}>
          First{" "}
        </Button>
        <Divider
          variant="middle"
          orientation="vertical"
          sx={{
            background: "#FFF",
            borderWidth: 2,
            height: "unset"
          }}
        />
        <Button sx={{ background: "#4c6c7b", color: "#FFF", py: 2 }}>
          Second{" "}
        </Button>
        <Divider
          variant="middle"
          orientation="vertical"
          sx={{
            background: "#FFF",
            borderWidth: 2,
            height: "unset"
          }}
        />
        <Button sx={{ background: "#4c6c7b", color: "#FFF", py: 2 }}>
          Last{" "}
        </Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It is a little difficult to change the height of the border between buttons, so I gave `Divider` between buttons.

I hope this will help a little.